# Why Eclipse error log show error "failed to instantiate"

Tags: android

Error Log shows error `org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.view.SingleWeatherInfoView` failed to instantiate

Package name:`org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.view`

Class name: `SingleWeatherInfoView`

Please help me to get out of the error.

My error log
[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6MIF.png)

```
package org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.views;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Map;

import org.anddev.android.weatherforecast.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * The View capable of showing a WeatehrIcon + a Temperature-TextView.
 */
public class SingleWeatherInfoView extends LinearLayout {

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private ImageView myWeatherImageView = null;
    private TextView myTempTextView = null;

    // ===========================================================
    // Constructors
    // ===========================================================

    public SingleWeatherInfoView(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }


    public SingleWeatherInfoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) //,Map inflateParams
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        /* Setup the ImageView that will show weather-icon. */
        this.myWeatherImageView = new ImageView(context);
        this.myWeatherImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dunno));

        /* Setup the textView that will show the temperature. */
        this.myTempTextView = new TextView(context);
        this.myTempTextView.setText("? °C");
        this.myTempTextView.setTextSize(16);
        this.myTempTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.create("Tahoma", Typeface.BOLD));


        /* Add child views to this object. */
        this.addView(this.myWeatherImageView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        this.addView(this.myTempTextView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    // ===========================================================
    // Getter & Setter
    // ===========================================================

    public void reset() {
        this.myWeatherImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                R.drawable.dunno));
        this.myTempTextView.setText("? °C");
    }

    /** Sets the Child-ImageView of this to the URL passed. */
    public void setRemoteImage(URL aURL) {
        try {
            URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            bis.close();
            is.close();
            this.myWeatherImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            /* Reset to 'Dunno' on any error. */
            this.myWeatherImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources()
                    .getDrawable(R.drawable.dunno));
        }
    }

    public void setTempCelcius(int aTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aTemp + " °C");
    }

    public void setTempFahrenheit(int aTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aTemp + " °F");
    }

    public void setTempFahrenheitMinMax(int aMinTemp, int aMaxTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aMinTemp + "/" + aMaxTemp + " °F");
    }

    public void setTempCelciusMinMax(int aMinTemp, int aMaxTemp) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText("" + aMinTemp + "/" + aMaxTemp + " °C");
    }

    public void setTempString(String aTempString) {
        this.myTempTextView.setText(aTempString);
    }
}
```

Comment: `post your SingleWeatherInfoView.java`

Comment: Now You can see my source code

Comment: are you startActivity with this class ?

Comment: No dear I have startActivity in another class

Comment: when you post question mind that always post full logcat here,its key to unlock a lock...

Comment: there is no error in Logcat bu for more detail about the question you can see by copying the URL "stackoverflow.com/questions/11467727/my-weather-forecast-android-application-doesnt-show-temperature"